# generate random querystring on script src path

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have my script reference where I would like to add a random querystring to it so I can prevent the browser to used a cached version.

```
<script src="dist/scripts/app.js?random=RandomString"></script>
```

I would like `RandomString` to be a Guid or whatever, just something unique.

Is there any way of doing this in a smooth way? Preferable by using angular. Otherwise I take what I get.

Comment: Has to be a string? Would you not go for `app.js?v=2`?

Comment: No it could be a guid or whatever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script src="dist/scripts/app.js?random={{getRandom()}}"></script>
```

controller

```
$scope.getRandom = function() {
return Math.random();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it in a C# and .cshtml solution...

We have a class that is going to generate a querystring for this, and keep it as a static string. This lets us keep the same value until the app pool is recycled, so browsers won't have to reload assets every time.

```
public static class UrlHelper
{
    public static string AssetReloadQueryString
    {
          get
          {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_assetReloadQueryString))
            {
                _assetReloadQueryString = $"version={Guid.NewGuid().ToString()}";
            }

            return _assetReloadQueryString;
          }
       }

        private static string _assetReloadQueryString;
      }
}
```

Obviously, if you **do** want to force reload on every single page load, you can just return

```
$"version={Guid.NewGuid().ToString()}"
```

and not bother putting it into a static string.

And then you so the src for your javascript and css files like this:

```
<script src="~/assets/js/forms.js?@Project.UrlHelper.AssetReloadQueryString"></script>
```